# how to install keras_contrib in google colab?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I want to apply instance normalization in my generator of 'GAN' and I am implementing my model in 'Google Colab', I am having trouble installing 'Keras_contrib'

I have tried the following code:

'''

```
!git clone https://www.github.com/keras-team/keras-contrib.git

!cd keras-contrib

!python setup.py install
```

'''

fatal: destination path 'keras-contrib' already exists and is not an empty directory.
python3: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: you should do 
`%cd keras-contrib`

Comment: Thanks! it helped me a lot. Earlier I need to give absolute path and now this made my work easier.

Answer (score 2):

Use this command
`!pip install git+https://www.github.com/keras-team/keras-contrib.git`

Comment: I have tried one more thing i first downloaded kera-contrib github directory on  my local system with [link] (git clone https://www.github.com/keras-team/keras-contrib.git) then i compressed it, then uploaded it on google colab -> unzip the compressed file with  ''' !unzip filename.zip ''' ran ''' python /content/filename/setup.py install